# Where to find a picture from photo library on the file system?

Tags: photos.app, macos

Using the get info on a picture inside the photo library, I'm getting a name a can't find on the file system anywhere in `~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/....`

Where can I get the physical location of a file ?

Comment: Assuming this is about the same topic as https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/391989/delete-picture-from-the-photo-library-using-the-command-line: Why don't you just delete the file from within Photos so the library will stay consistant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oddly enough you **did** get the physical location of the picture.

It is *inside the Photos Library.photolibrary package*

While you can open that package file by right-clicking or control-clicking on that file and selecting "Show Package Contents" it is generally not a good idea to do this as just deleting the original will not remove it from the Photos.app. In other words the next time you launch Photos that picture will seemingly still be there.

Your best bet is to delete the picture from within the Photos.app and stay out of the photolibrary package.